# Problems with FileIO

Tags: java, file-io

[Picture of the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn6qf.jpg)
When I run my code in Netbeans it can't find my file. But if I open and run in IntelliJ it works fine. I can't get my head around the problem

I have tried the long path for the file but it doesn't seem to work either

```
 public void readFile() {


    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Nummerplader.txt"))){
        //String line;
        String items[];
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            items = sc.nextLine().split(":");
            //items = line.split(":");
            districtMap.put(items[0],items[1]);

        }
        //System.out.println("Map:" + districtMap );



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Malte\Documents\GitHub\VOP1\VOPEksamensforberedelse\Nummerplader.txt (Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet)
KC39078: Privat personvogn fra district code does not exist
kc49900: Ambulance el. lign. fra district code does not exist
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
KO47078: Hyrevogn fra district code does not exist
EN19022: Motorcykel fra district code does not exist
EN190220: Invalid length on license plate 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at Lesson_04.opg2_numberplates.NumberPlates.readFile(NumberPlates.java:49)
    at Lesson_04.opg2_numberplates.NumberPlates.<init>(NumberPlates.java:42)
    at Lesson_04.opg2_numberplates.NumberPlates.main(NumberPlates.java:99)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Different IDE's use different default storage and retrieval directories.  Try creating your file with a full path name including drive letter.

Comment: I already tried that. Still can't open my file

Comment: Try specifying a string only, no File class.  Can you create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The other possibilities are 1) wrong file name or 2) invisible characters in you file name.

Comment: It works if I make a different project. Can it be because GIt have hade an odd path to the file ?

Comment: Possibly.  I have seen file names that couldn't be read either because they or the code in the IDE used UTF-8 vs UTF-16 or some other encoding where the characters could not be seen.